# soft link to non existant server?

Tags: samba

I inherited a bunch of xls files and a dts that imports them all into sql.
the server the dts is looking for no longer exists (FS1)

Any kind soul knows a way to make that any petition to FS1(non existant) is somewhat redirected to new server (NEWFS)? (without renaming NEWFS)
if not I guess I will have to replace paths in dts but I was hoping to avoid that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You give way too little information. The Wikipedia disambiguation page for DTS lists fifteen possible meanings. Please specify at least your basic system architecture, platform and relevant applications.

Answer (score 1):

If the paths are the same on the old and new servers, then adding an entry (new fileserver's IP and old fileserver's name) to the local `hosts` file on the server that the DTS task runs on would probably work. Try this on a test server first.

Alternatively adding a DNS alias might help but you might not want to do this if you're trying to remove all references to the old server.

Right thing to do is to update the DTS task.